# How can I find Inbound shipment ID of inventory by its SKU ID using MWS API?

Tags: amazon-mws

I have only SKU ID of the product, now I need to find its inbound shipment ID and get shipment content.

For example:
If by shipment with ID 'TESTSHP' was transported 3 products:

```
1.name_of_product='TV', SKU='PRDCT-1-1', quantity='1',...
2.name_of_product='PC', SKU='PRDCT-2-2', quantity='2',...
3.name_of_product='Tablet', SKU='PRDCT-3-10', quantity='10',...
```

in app user enters only this part 'PRDCT' of the SKU ID, and I need to display list of all products transported with same shipment ID.
result i have to display:

```
1.name_of_product='TV', SKU='PRDCT-1-1', quantity='1',...
2.name_of_product='PC', SKU='PRDCT-2-2', quantity='2',...
3.name_of_product='Tablet', SKU='PRDCT-3-10', quantity='10',...
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a SKU and want to know what shipment ID(s) that SKU belongs to.  The only way I can suggest is to call [ListInboundShipments](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_ListInboundShipments.html) with the ShipmentStatus you want and loop through them looking for the SKU that you have, 'PRDCT'. Potentially many times, depending on how many shipments you have.  Once you find that SKU on a particular shipment, get that shipment ID and call, [ListInboundShipmentItems](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_ListInboundShipmentItems.html) with that shipment ID for a list of all other SKUs on it.

There is no operation I know of where you can search by SKU.